Distance between two convex sets
Setting

If $A$ an $B$ are two symmetric matrices, we denote by $A >B$ when the matrice $A-B$ is definite positive.

In $\left(\mathbb{R}^{*}_{+} \right)^4$, consider the convex set $$ \Lambda = \left\{ \begin{pmatrix}
x_1 & 0\\
0 & x_2 
\end{pmatrix} > \begin{pmatrix}
y_1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 
\end{pmatrix} + \begin{pmatrix}
y_2 & y_2 \\
y_2 & y_2 
\end{pmatrix}  \right\} $$ and consider also the perturbated convex set $$ \Lambda_r = \left\{ \begin{pmatrix}
x_1 & 0\\
0 & x_2 
\end{pmatrix} > \begin{pmatrix}
y_1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 
\end{pmatrix} + \begin{pmatrix}
0 & r y_1 \\
r y_1 & r^2 y_1 
\end{pmatrix} + \begin{pmatrix}
y_2 & y_2 \\
y_2 & y_2 
\end{pmatrix}  \right\} $$  for $|r| = \frac{1}{100}$ say.


Question

How can we prove that we have, for any $p = (x_1,x_2,y_1,y_2) \in \Lambda_r$, the following control $$ \text{dist}(p, \Lambda) \lesssim \min(x_1,x_2) ?$$

Remark

Of course, this inequality is useful only in the regime $x_1$ or $x_2$ small.


Simply add $y_1$ to both $x_1,x_2$

Hi ! Thx but I am not exactly sure what do you mean... Do you mean that $\text{dist}(p,\Lambda)$ is $\simeq \min(x_1 + y_1, x_2 +y_1)$ and that since $x_1 \gtrsim y_1$ and $x_2 \gtrsim y_1$ we have the desired estimate ?

I mean that the quadruple $(x_1+y_1,x_2+y_1,y_1,y_2)\in \Lambda$ and $|y_1|\leqslant \min (x_1,100x_2)$

Hmmmm I didn't notice this belonging... But isn't it a bit weird ? I guess the $100x_2$ comes from $r= \frac{1}{100}$.. But why is it blowing as $r \rightarrow 0$ ? It should be the other way around right ? I mean $r$ very small implies $\Lambda_r$ very close to $\Lambda$...

Possibly, I did not think about $r$ varying

Hmmm okey actually you can add $r^2 y_1$ and then you are still good :) ! Thx a lot !

$2r^2y_1$ sorry

Hm, why is this good?

Hmm no sorry my claim is wrong, I miscalculated that $2r^2 y_1 I_2 > \begin{pmatrix}
0 & ry_1 \
ry_1 & r^2y_1
\end{pmatrix}$... But this is wrong..

If $m:=\min(x_1,x_2)$, then $m\geqslant y_2$, thus $(x_1+2m,x_2+2m,y_1,y_2)\in \Lambda$

Hmmm okey I am going to check that thanks a lot... But still I think the $\lesssim$ should depend on $r$ in a decreasing way...

@FedorPetrov do you think we can add a $r$ parameter in the control ..?..

Now I think that $\Lambda_r\subset \Lambda$. Or $r$ may be negative?

Hmmm.. well when $\Lambda = \left{ \text{Diag}(x_1,x_2) >  \text{Diag}(y_1,y_2)  \right}$, yes any perturbation is included in $\Lambda$... but yes $r$ may be negative, that is why I specified $|r|$ small.

@FedorPetrov why do you think there is inclusion ..?..
